# Download json using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have webapi returning me data and that data i need to download in a txt file.
I have done it using below code and i am getting result as desired. I am somehow looking for a better approach .Is there any angular way to do this ?

```
$scope.downloadResponseAsInfoFile = function (response) {
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = "info.txt";
    var data = "text/json;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(response);
    link.href = "data:" + data;
    link.click();
};
```

how can i handle exception in case i dont get response from server.

Comment: What calls your function? Where does `response` come from? Presumably you'd handle HTTP errors there

Comment: write if condition based on your response

Comment: @Phil its like this  var response = myService.downloaInfo(id, name);
        if (response != null && response != "") { 
            $scope.downloadResponseAsInfoFile (response)
        }

Answer (score 5):

In `downloadResponseAsInfoFile`, if response is coming through http call than you need to handle exception according to `response`.

```
$scope.downloadResponseAsInfoFile = function (response) {
    // if this response is coming through http call than make condition according to http response.statusCode
    //check response is undefined, null or empty
    if(typeof response == 'undefined' || response == null || response == "")
        return ;

    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = "info.txt";
    var data = "text/json;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(response);
    link.href = "data:" + data;
    link.click();
};
```

Angular Way: [article](https://techdev.de/an-angularjs-directive-to-download-pdf-files/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use angular's $http provider for fetching data from the web api
See documentation here : - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

```
$http.get(url).then(function (response) {
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.download = "info.txt";
var data = "text/json;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(response);
link.href = "data:" + data;
link.click();
};
```

Comment: slight addition to the above code:-
$http.get(url).then(function successCallback(response) {
     //yourcode
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    //errmsg
  });

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others

Comment: @Odera thanks for the tip , I have appropriately provided additional info to make the answer helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using native JavaScript API - [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob) and [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) saveAs No need to deal with any HTML elements at all -

```
var data = {
    key: 'value'
};
var fileName = 'myData.json';

// Create a blob of the data
var fileToSave = new Blob([JSON.stringify(data)], {
    type: 'application/json',
    name: fileName
});

// Save the file
saveAs(fileToSave, fileName);
```

Just paste the above code in your controller's callback.